# RenderControl in asp.net not getting the html i added into that control using JQuery

Tags: asp.net

I am using a jQuery editor and when the user hits the submit button i put the content into asp.net Panel control as html and then when i render this Panel the html i added is not
retrieved.

```
function MoveData() {
        var sHTML = $('#summernote_1').code();

        // dvFrontPageHtml is asp.net Panel
        $('[id*=dvFrontPageHtml]').html(sHTML);

        setTimeout(function () {
            javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$ContentPlaceHolderBody$lnkSave', '');
        }, 10000);

        return false;
    }


 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
        dvFrontPageHtml.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        string Message = sb.ToString();
```

The **message** does not returning the html added.

I dont want to use jQuery ajax call as of now.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

without seeing all the relevant code its hard to pinpoint the problem.

but im pretty sure you are trying to find an ASP.net control by its **serverside ID** from **clientside**.
`dvFrontPageHtml` is the Controls ID by which asp.net identifies it, and unless you explicitly tell ASP.Net otherwise, it will generate a different ID for the control to be used by scripts at **clientside**

you need to retrieve the panel's **clientside ID** thats being generated for it by asp.net

you do it by a preprocessor directive `<%=dvFrontPageHtml.ClientID%>`:

```
$('[id*=<%=dvFrontPageHtml.ClientID%>]').html(sHTML);
```

alternatively, if you want the **clientside ID** to be same as the **serverside ID**, you can set the control's attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

**UPDATE:**

from your comment it seems the problem is elsewhere. what comes to mind, is that `RenderControl()` takes the control as it was when sent to the client in the Response. but the control is not being submitted to the server in next Request, so you will not be able to retrieve its altered html.

what you can do as a workaround, is hook into ASP.NET's build in postback mechanism, and submit the panel's html as a custom event argument:

**for the example, lets assume this is our html:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="dvFrontPageHtml" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">test</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="BT_Test" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
```

**this will be our javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    // add custom event handler for the submit button
    $("#<%=BT_Test.ClientID%>").click(function (ev) {
        //prevent the default behavior and stop it from submitting the form
        ev.preventDefault();

        //alter the panels html as you require
        var sHTML = $('#summernote_1').code();
        $('[id*=dvFrontPageHtml]').html(sHTML);

        //cause a postback manually, with target = BTCLICK and argument = panel's html
        __doPostBack('BTCLICK', $('[id*=dvFrontPageHtml]').outerHTML());
    });
});
```

**and here we capture the postback on serverside:**

```
//we monitor page load 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Message;
    //check if its a postback
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //monitor for our custom target "BTCLICK"
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].CompareTo("BTCLICK") == 0)
        {
            // retrieve the panels html from the event argument
            Message = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had cross checked the html is going in the div and i can see it using firebug but the strange issue is it is not getting in server side. Strangely only the dynamic added html is not retrieved. Let me know if i am not clear,